# Local Notification only firing once?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localnotification

I have a local notification set to fire on the specified date when a user changes the date

on a UIDatePicker. However, when I ran the app, the notification fired correctly, but when

I went and made a small change, then ran it again, the notification didn't fire. Here's my

code, please help!

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

// Get the current date
NSDate *pickerDate = [datepicker date];

// Break the date up into components
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                               fromDate:pickerDate];
// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
[dateComps release];


UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;

localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Timer";
// Set the action button
localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
```

Comment: what small change did you make?

Comment: I changed the text that is displayed in the Notification.